# simulate a real world car on SUMO

Tags: traffic-simulation

Aoa, is there any way to simulate the latitude and longitude of android hardware by using GSM values of any android device on **SUMO**.

Answer (score 0):

The fcd-output can be used to generate lon-lat traces for vehicles and pedestrians. Afterwards the tool traceExporter.py can be used to convert the trace to various trace file formats. See http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/FCDOutput
and http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/TraceExporter